# Recovering an Encrypted Home Partition Overwritten by LUKS

Tags: encryption, 16.04, data-recovery, luks, ubiquity

After aborting a recent installation attempt of Ubuntu 16.04 (which I've since installed without a separate home partition), I discovered that my existing encrypted home partition is no longer accessible.  Evidently, I had re-formatted my encrypted home partition as LUKS even though I had never even committed to any changes by pressing 'Continue'.  When I attempt to access the partition after unlocking it with my password, I receive the message, "The unlocked device does not have a recognizable file system on it."  The partition had been originally formatted as EXT4 and I believe used encryptfs (whatever was the standard at the time of the release of Ubuntu 14.04).  How do I fix this?!!  I've created an image of the partition using TestDisk and when I opened it using PhotoRec, PhotoRec only found two .gpg files, a .tib file, three non-playable .mp3 files, a .dbx file, and an .ab file. Unfortunately, I had stupidly not backed up the 600GB partition as I had never had an issue with an Ubuntu installation before, and now I'm regretting it!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How much time did the failed/aborted installer spend writing to the drive?

It would take a long time to overwrite all 600GB, and I'm not sure but just setting up LUKS it *may not* attempt (the recommended secure practice) to overwrite with zeros before creating a filesystem - and it didn't successfully create a filesystem from the "no recognizable filesystem" message.

It *may* have been able to run `wipefs` though, which may explain why testdisk couldn't find anything.

Your testdisk & photorec attempts are what I'd suggest too, but photorec should have found more than just a handful of corrupted files out of 600GB. Unless photorec can't recognize eCryptfs files, but it's [File Formats Recovered by Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec) page says it should know  "`.ecr` &
`.eCryptfs` Encrypted file by eCryptfs".

But, you may not have imaged enough of the drive. The new home partition that was created may not be in the same place as the old home partition. If you had the old home's start/end sectors you could see if it matches, and try imaging/recovering just where the old home used to be...

Trying testdisk's analyze quick & deeper search on the entire drive couldn't hurt now (as long as the drive isn't failing), and/or having photorec search the entire drive for only eCryptfs files...

(I've heard about the Ubuntu installer overwriting things by accident before, don't remember the pressing "continue" detail, but it's not encouraging to hear. Makes me not want to have any irreplaceable drives even powered on when installing. Definitely want a backup next time)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  It wasn't long at all before I had aborted the installation.  It should have never proceeded to do anything before I continued to the next step.  For one thing, the Ubiquity developers should have realised that many people only upgrade from LTS to LTS so might not know about the new changes in encryption.  In previous releases, I was accustomed to being prompted to input a password for the encryption so that the /home partition would be unlocked upon login, so I had thought it was safe to select my /home partition to be mounted as /home and tick it for encryption.  Once I ticked the box and saw that it had automatically selected the 'Format' box, as well, I panicked and immediately reverted the changes.  Once I determined that I wasn't sure how to proceed, I aborted the installation altogether.

Yes, I should have backed up my /home partition, but in my six years of using Ubuntu, I NEVER had any issues with a fresh installation of Ubuntu.  The Ubiquity folks really dropped the ball on this one.  It would be nice if one of them could post to this thread and at least tell me what exactly their installer did to my drive.

During the preliminary installation process, I never requested any re-partitioning, so the /home partition that I had selected was the exact same one for 14.04.  I've tried the "Quick & Deeper" search on the entire drive, and it finds nothing.  The file system is just gone.  I wish I knew what Ubiquity did!  I'm leaving the partition alone and hoping that SOMEONE will know of a way to salvage my data, but it's not looking good.....

(P.S.  I know this isn't an answer, but the "Add Comment" option didn't allow me to enter enough characters to reply.)

Comment: There should have been a few regular files in the partition that should've been found by photorec, at least the eCryptfs config files - maybe try the latest testdisk/photorec? You could try using a hex editor (like Bless) to look at the partition data directly, it may be hard to tell LUKS from eCryptfs data, but all zeros would stand out, maybe search for a few words or eCryptfs key that wasn't encrypted... (And, there should be an "Edit" link (under the Q?) to edit the question & add more details, I *think* this is it (it is for me anyway) http://askubuntu.com/posts/765985/edit )

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into Bless.  I had installed TestDisk from the Software Centre, so I'll look for a newer copy.

Comment: Just checked the webpage http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download looks like 7.0 is the latest stable release, 7.1 is a WIP / beta. Not sure which is in Ubuntu's repos, 14.04 may have 6.14

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04's repositories have 7.0-1.